# Preg Replace html apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, encoding, preg-replace

I use this code to make user tags and hashtags work on my small site.

```
$string = $text;

$pattern = '/(^|\W)(@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))/';
$replacement = '$1<a class="blue" href="/app/profile/$3">$2</a>';
$text =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
$string = $text;

$pattern = '/(^|\W)(#([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))/';
$replacement = '$1<a class="blue" href="/app/find/search/$3">$2</a>';
$text =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo  $text;
```

My database saves all pieces of text like this:

```
he&#039;s
```

(he's)

However when it outputs through this code the words are not normalised and the output is as follows:

```
he&amp;<a class="blue" href="/app/find/search/039">#039</a>;s
```

When it shold just be "he's"
How can I get the preg replace to see it as an apostrophe?

Comment: You didn't allow `&` and `;` in your `$pattern`, so they're being stripped out.

Comment: Was there something you didn't understand in my answer? I saw no comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second pattern to this.

```
$pattern = '/(^|[^\w\&])(#([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))/';
```

What it does is, it will not match if the hashtag is immediately preceded by `&`. So `&#039;` wont be matched. Also `&#sometag` also wont be matched, but I believe that is fine since you are already not matching the hashtag if it is preceded by some text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a look-behind assertion:

```
/(?<=^|\s)(#|@)(\w+)/
```

*Preceded by either the beginning of a string or a space (including tabs, newlines, etc.), a hash or at symbol followed by at least one "word like" character.*

So:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|\s)(#|@)(\w+)/', function($match) {
    switch ($match[1]) {
        case '#':
            $format = '<a class="blue href="/app/find/search/%s">%s</a>';
            break;

        case '@':
            $format = '<a class="blue href="/app/profile/%s">%s</a>';
            break;

        default:
            return $match[0];
    }

    return sprintf($format, urlencode($match[2]), $match[1] . $match[2]);
}, $string);
```